# How to print info when 2 things are correct and to use the input fuction when the those two things are incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a controlled assessment. I have this code :

```
# user Qualifications
print("\nQualification Level")

print("\n""\"AP\" = Apprentice",
      "\n\"FQ\" = Fully-Qualified")
user_qual = input("Enter you Qualification Level: ")
```

When the `user_qual` is equal to `AP` or `FQ` I want to print "correct". But when the `user_qual` is not equal to either `AP` or `FQ`, I want to print an error message and re-ask the `user_qual` input question. However, I tried many different ways but couldn't do it.

Please just give a simple solution and nothing complicated. I am just a beginner and learning the basics.

Comment: *"I tried many different ways but couldn't do it."* You *should* add those, it is better to show your attempts and where you failed than expecting us to write everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn your code into a function so it can be called again, if the criteria are not met:

```
def prompt():
    # user Qualifications
    print('\nQualification Level')
    print('\n"AP" = Apprentice\n"FQ" = Fully-Qualified')

    user_qual = input('Enter you Qualification Level: ')

    if user_qual not in ('AP','FQ'):
        prompt() # Criteria not met, so ask again
    print('Correct!') # Criteria met, don't ask again


# Call the function the first time
prompt()
```

As @IanAuld mentions in the comments, if you want to allow users to provide the answer (ie. AP) in a case insensitive manner (so users can type 'ap' instead), you would want to convert the case before evaluating it, like so:

```
if user_qual.upper() not in ('AP','FQ'):
    ...rest of code...
```

Comment: It's often useful in cases like this to normalize the input with either `upper()` or `lower()` (in this case `upper()` would be best) so that users aren't presented with an error for entering `'ap'`. This makes for a much more pleasant UX.

Comment: @IanAuld - I agree, though I wanted to throw as little at OP as possible as they state they are a beginner, etc - so just showing the basics. I'll add your comment as a note in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining the qualification levels within a variable. In this simple case a [tuple](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html) suffices, but if there were to be more qualification levels, a [dictionary](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/dictionaries.html) would make more sense.

```
qualification_levels = ('AP', 'FQ')
print("\n""\"AP\" = Apprentice",
      "\n\"FQ\" = Fully-Qualified")
user_qual = input("Enter you Qualification Level: ")
if user_qual in qualification_levels:
    print('correct!')
else:
    print('ERROR!!!')
```